# Storing jquery div id value into php variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem and need a solution. I have a server sent event which gets updated to a div id everytime when there is a change in the database. Now my question is how to get the value from that div id and save it to a PHP variable.

```
<script>
    if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined")
    {
        var source=new EventSource("bookcounterevent.php");
        source.onmessage=function(event)
        {
            document.getElementById("bookcounter").innerHTML=event.data;
        };
    }
    else
    {
    document.getElementById("bookcounter").innerHTML="Please update your browser!!";
    }
    </script>
    <div id="bookcounter"></div>
```

The above codes update the `<div id="bookcounter"></div>`, I want the value which I receive at id **bookcounter**, I want to save it to a php variable say `$book`. How can that be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: doesn't make sense to send the data to browser, and send it right back. Get it out of the php function that sends it. Would help if you gave a better description of what you are trying to do

Comment: I dont think you can store it in a php var (on that page), because the page is already 'executed' so the php process is already finish once result is return to the browser (unless you are doing 'Long Polling'). What you could do is store in a hidden field so you can post it back to the server if need or use a session

Comment: @R.S I'm using a long polling method, so now tell me how can I move forward from there.

Comment: @user1731476  php runs on server, javascript in client. It is not clear at all what you want to be able to do with regard to "php variable"

Comment: @user1731476 What info are you trying to 'store' in this php var?

Comment: @R.S See the div id return a number say 6, I just want that 6 to go into $book

Comment: @user1731476 How does this id affect the php code been executed?

Comment: @R.S See I want to change the selection of two seperate div's based on  value i receive from div id.

Comment: @user1731476 Since this seem to be client side, why dont you use javascript to select the div?

Comment: @R.S I'm confused how to do it. can u post the code as an answer to this question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18946/discussion-between-r-s-and-user1731476)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
#notification {
    color:green;
}
#nonotification {
    color:red;
}
</style>
<script> 
      if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined") 
      { 
          var source=new EventSource("bookcounterevent.php"); 

          source.onmessage=function(event) 
          { 
              if(parseInt(event.data) > 0){ 
                document.getElementById("bookcounter").innerHTML=event.data; 
              } 
              else{ 
                document.getElementById("nonotification").innerHTML= 'nothing to display'; 
              } 
          }
      } 
      else 
      { 
        document.getElementById("bookcounter").innerHTML="Please update your browser!!"; 
      } 
  </script>

<div id="notification"></div>
<div id="nonotification"></div>
```